# wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2) (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby

My goal is for a user to enter their screen resolution and store it in `screen_size`. I did this, but I have an error.

```
class Screen
  attr_accessor :screen_size, :info

  def initialize(screen_size, info)
    @screen_size = screen_size
    @info = info
  end
end

my_info = Screen.new("What is you're resolution?")
my_screen = Screen.new(gets.chomp)
# >> in `initialize': wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2) (ArgumentError)
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: It is not clear in what format you expect the input, and what arguments they should correspond to.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing wrong arguments to `Screen.new`. Your `initialize` method expects two arguments and you are passing only one.

Try this:

```rb
screen = Screen.new(gets.chomp, "What is you're resolution?")
```

Answer (score 0):

`gets.chomp` returns one value (which is whatever you typed in before pressing enter). That method expects two. If you're entering something like "1024 768", then you could split the input by the space. Something like this:

```
w, h = gets.chomp.split(' ')
my_screen = Screen.new(w, h)
```